# Parser for Pipfiles (get a list of all packages used in a Pipfile)

Tags: python, pip, python-packaging, pipfile

Is there any parser out there for reading in a Pipfile and returning a list of all packages used in the Pipfile?

If not, how would one go about this? I was thinking a regular expression could do the job, but I am not sufficiently acquainted with the structure of Pipfiles to confirm that is the case.

Comment: are you asking about requirements.txt (ie `pip install -r requirements.txt`)?

Comment: No, I'm asking about a `Pipfile`, which is the new standard that replace the `requirements.txt` file @JoranBeasley

Comment: it is not a new standard... at all ... its a 3rd party library that aims to provide an alternative package management ...  that said here is the library and it includes a parser https://github.com/pypa/pipfile

Comment: 'Standard' was the wrong word, it just seems like "use pipenv" (which uses Pipfiles) is the standard advice in a lot of Python communities online. Anyways, thank you @JoranBeasley

Comment: I think most now recommend python poetry package ... well probably 50/50 ... with another 50 just using normal requirements.txt

Answer (score 7, accepted):

first install pipfile    `pip install pipfile`.

then just use the parser it provides

```
from pipfile import  Pipfile
parsed = Pipfile.load(filename=pipfile_path)
```