# How to read specific key-value entry under file with topics sectioned by brackets?

Tags: bash, shell, sh

Assuming the following file structure:

```
[topic1]
key1 = "value1"
key2 = "value2"
[topic2]
key1 = "value3"
.
.
.
```

How can I extract value2 from key2 from topic1 to the shell?I'm used to use jq to read json file and get key-value entries but I have no idea to extract the key value in this situation.

Comment: Is this an INI file? If so you can use an INI parser

Comment: Actually is a Pipfile, but it could be any other type of file with multi-section key-value entries.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53015909/948550

Answer (score 1):

Currently I have the following script working:

```
sed -nr "/^\[topic1\]/ { :l /^key2[ ]*=/ { s/.*=[ ]*//; p; q;}; n; b l;}" file | tr -d '"'
```

Seems to work but I was looking for a more simplified way to do this.

Comment: Include that in your question to improve your question which is supposed to contain a [mcve] including concise, testable sample input plus expected output plus what yopu'd tried so far (i.e. the script in this "answer"), don't post it separately as an answer. See [ask] if that's not clear.

Comment: That's not bad, except that if the desired key is not present in the given topic, it continues the search in the following topics.

Answer (score 1):

all `sed` -

> EDIT - I removed the specificity of which topic needed to follow `topic1`. Now any new `[topic` will end the range, so order shouldn't matter.

```
sed -En '/^\[topic1\]/,/^\[topic/ { /^key2\s*=/ { s/^.*=\s*"([^"]+)".*/\1/; p; } }'
```

Breakout:

`sed -En` says use extended matching but don't print anything unless requested.

`/^\[topic1\]/,/^\[topic/ { ... }`
says do the stuff between the braces only between the section headers for topic1 and topic2 (inclusive).

Within that,
`/^key2\s*=/ { ... }`
says do the stuff between *these* braces only on the key2 lines.

Then, once you've found the key2 between topic1 and the next topic,
`s/^.*=\s*"([^"]+)".*/\1/;` says replace the whole line with just the value part between the quotes, and then `p`rint the result.

Formatted:

```
sed -En '
  /^\[topic1\]/,/^\[topic/ {
    /^key2\s*=/ { 
      s/^.*=\s*"([^"]+)".*/\1/;
      p;
    }
  }
'
```

Remove the `;`'s and that will work for non-GNU `sed` as well, I think.

Comment: topics are not ordered, so how to define only one?

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk -F' *= *"|"$' '
    gsub(/^\[|]$/,"") { topic=$0; next }
    (topic=="topic1") && ($1=="key2") { print $2 }
' file
value2
```

Answer (score 0):

> topics are not ordered, so how to define only one?

Just specify `/^\[/` (the beginning of a following topic) as the second pattern (end) of the address range, e. g.:

```
sed -n '/^\[topic1]/,/^\[/s/key2 = "\(.*\)"/\1/p' file
```